# Qt ignore makefiles, .pro.user files

Tags: file, qt, mercurial, makefile, ignore

I develop Qt-based project and use Mercurial repository (bitbucket.org service) for version control.

Each time I do commit in repository, there are some files which contains only date-time changes in headers. So each commit I should check each file that it has major changes, not only time stamp.

Could I add makefiles (Makefile, Makefile.Debug, Makefile.Release) and .pro.user file ext. to ignore list? 
I mean is it possible to regenerate them via launching qmake tool from Qt Creator?

Comment: Files generated by the build system should never be version controlled.

Comment: @pmr: except for configure scripts, if you want to have your project easily buildable from a repository.

Comment: So any makefile could be ignored without any consequence, right?

Comment: @MaximKorobov Probably, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makefiles are generated by running qmake (either from command line or from Qt Creator).

.pro.user file is created by Qt Creator when a project is created or opened and contains stuff like editor configuration for a given project.

All those files shouldn't be added to VSC, so you should definitely ignore them.

Comment: Unfortunately `.pro.user` file contains also **run** and **build** settings (like directories, variables, `make` parameters that get lost i.e. cannot be re-generated. In other words, I'm solving the same problem as @maxim-korobov, but skipping `.user` file is not a solution. I miss a Qt Creator setting  disabling superfluous write of the timestamp (as I have 2 environments on two different machines where I want to reuse `.user` settings).

Comment: @MartinDvorak Old thread, but there's also a [`.pro.shared`](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-sharing-project-settings.html) file. "It has the same XML structure as a .pro.user file, but only contains the settings to share.". You can create your own by just copying across what you want to share.

Comment: @wardw Great - this is exactly what I was looking for!