# How do I get a textedit box to both resize and not have the scrollbars go wonky?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Long story short I am trying to append text to a textEdit box in Qt as a process is being executed...However the textedit box needs to be resized as the entire application is resized. Upon doing that the scrollbars on the textedit begin to not work and text is cut off inside the box.

My project is here: https://github.com/voncloft/VPacman

Source code working on: https://github.com/voncloft/VPacman/blob/master/untitled1/mainwindow.cpp

The following code "messes everything up"

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)
{


ui->plainTextEdit->setGeometry(MainWindow::width()-300,0,280,40);
ui->textEdit->resize(MainWindow::width()-30,MainWindow::height()-30);
ui->listWidget->resize(MainWindow::width()-30,300);

}
```

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't commit build artifacts, such as .o and moc files, nor should you commit the .pro.user file

Comment: Why would that be the case?

Comment: Because they're generated either by qmake and compilation or by qt creator

Comment: You can look at this answer [Qt ignore makefiles, .pro.user files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873772/10996546)